# powershell regex filename matching

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm new to using both powershell and regex but think it's the solution to verifying filename formats in a folder. The filenames should typically look like...

"01234 - Corres - Example title of my study - 2015-12-03.msg"

and using this script to do the matching...

```
$MyStudyPath = "C:\Users\higginsr4\Test\StudyExamples\SmallMsgFolder"
$MyStudyNumber = "06327"
#Get-ChildItem -path $MyStudyPath -filter *.msg | where-object {$_.Name -match $($MyStudyNumber+' - corres - *' + '\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d.msg')}
Get-ChildItem -path $MyStudyPath -filter *.msg | where-object {$_.Name -match $($MyStudyNumber+' - corres - *')}
```

This code line...

```
Get-ChildItem -path $MyStudyPath -filter *.msg | where-object {$_.Name -match $($MyStudyNumber+' - corres - *')}
```

works fine but I'd like to be able to use the regex wildcard to match any "Example title of my study" followed by matching the date using regex with syntax in the commented out line in the above script. Problem is that this commented out line doesn't match anything and struggling to resolve the problem with matching the date using regex.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: https://www.debuggex.com/ could help you debugging your regex.

Answer (score 3):

Try this pattern `01234 - [cC]orres - [\w -]+? \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`.

Obviously, `01234` you can replace with the number you enter and concatenate pattern.

Then it matches `corres` or `Corres` followed by a sequence of word characters, space or hyphen, non-greedy (`[\w -]+?`) so it won't consume the date as well. Then it matches date: `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`, but you have to be sure about format. To include other formats you coud use something like this: `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mv8Uxo/2)

Comment: Many thanks for that. I would never have considered the 'non-greedy' aspect. Complex syntax...!

Comment: @RobCodyStuff Glad I could help. Accept the answer if it has helped you (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Comment: My script is designed to find filenames that don't conform to the expected format, so I placed a 'notmatch' in the script and tested it out on a live folder with real filenames. However, I had some unexpected results where what I considered good filenames were being listed as not matched. e.g.

"08302 - Corres - Collaboration Agreement and Site Agreements - 2017-03-08.msg"
                                      
Any suggestions as to why these are being classed as not matched?

Comment: @RobCodyStuff Put `\d{5}` instead of `01234` in my pattern - because it seems that you want match file starting with 5 digits instead of fixed number.

Comment: My updated script is provided below. I need to provide a match on the exact study number (e.g. "08302") and not just a match for any 5 digits at the beginning of the filename. PS - I added "(" and ")" into this "[\w -()]+?" code snippet so that round brackets would be accepted in the filename and wondered if this has broken the script.

$MyStudyPath = "C:\Users\higginsr4\Test\StudyExamples\8302 Carrie"
$MyStudyNumber = "08302"
Get-ChildItem -path $MyStudyPath -filter *.msg -recurse | where-object {$_.Name -notmatch $($MyStudyNumber+' - [cC]orres - [\w -()]+? \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')}

Comment: @RobCodyStuff Remember, you need to escape brackets: `\(` and `\)` to match them literally!

Comment: Think the "[\w -]" code snippet is the problem and is 'notmatching' if the study name does not include a '-' or ' '. Similarly with the round brackets I had defined earlier. How can I make these items listed in [\w -] optional? i.e. The study name description may have '-' or ' ' or '(' or ')' in the filename?

Comment: I think you want to use `[\w -\(\)]`.

Comment: Thanks. Modified script (I have implemented \ before the round brackets) to 
$MyStudyPath = "C:\Users\higginsr4\Test\StudyExamples\8302 Carrie"
$MyStudyNumber = "08302"
Get-ChildItem -path $MyStudyPath -filter *.msg -recurse | where-object {$_.Name -notmatch $($MyStudyNumber+' - [cC]orres - [\w -\(\)]+? \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')}
Still getting notmatches that appear to have "good" filenames. e.g.
"08302 - Corres - Outcome of Application for HRA - 2017-08-31.msg" and "08302 - Corres - Outcome of Initial Assessment - 2017-07-14.msg". Can you help describe why this is occurring? Thanks...

Comment: @RobCodyStuff Werid, I get match with my patter, [**see demo**](https://regex101.com/r/mv8Uxo/4)

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that I'm using a .NET based regex engine. I just moved the dash in the regex from this "[\w -\(\)\.\&]*" to this "[\w \(\)-\.\&]*" and it worked. i.e. Moved the '-'. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @RobCodyStuff If my answer has helped you then you should accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend another option to verify file names. How do you know all names are correct? Where clause omits incorrect matches. Try this one:

```
#sample data
"" | Out-file '01234 - Corres - Example title of my study - 2015-12-03.msg'                                                                                                                                                                                               
"" | Out-file '01234 - Word - My study - 2017-11-05.msg'                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
"" | Out-file '12345 - Other Word - My second study - 2012-10-12.msg'
"" | out-file unknown-name.msg

ls * | % {
  $match = [Regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<Code>\d+) - (?<Symbol>.+) - (?<Name>.+) - (?<Date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).msg')
  [pscustomobject]@{
    FullName = $_.Name;
    Success = $match.Success;
    Code = $match.Groups['Code'].Value;
    Symbol = $match.Groups['Symbol'].Value;
    Name = $match.Groups['Name'].Value;
    Date = if ($match.Success) { [DateTime]::Parse($match.Groups['Date'].Value, [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture) }
  }
} | ft
```

All names are matched and proper information is displayed (including date converted to DateTime type):

```
FullName                                                    Success Code  Symbol     Name                      Date               
--------                                                    ------- ----  ------     ----                      ----               
01234 - Corres - Example title of my study - 2015-12-03.msg    True 01234 Corres     Example title of my study 2015-12-03 00:00:00
01234 - Word - My study - 2017-11-05.msg                       True 01234 Word       My study                  2017-11-05 00:00:00
12345 - Other Word - My second study - 2012-10-12.msg          True 12345 Other Word My second study           2012-10-12 00:00:00
unknown-name.msg                                              False
```